# Is there an expression for asking two people to perform a task, but neither do it, assuming that the other will?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I'm somewhat familiar with the French "tomber entre deux chaises," which means "falling between two chairs", but it doesn't scan in English. Is there a common expression for this fairly common issue in English that I'm missing?

Comment: I've always called it the [***dissipation of responsibility***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dissipation+of+responsibility%22), but there are probably other terms.

Comment: 'Falling between two stools' exists, but has two meanings, each slightly different from what you require [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fall_between_two_stools)] (and has been covered before).

Comment: It almost certainly involves poor leadership on the part of the person delegating the task, not recognising the potential for this (and pre-empting it).

Comment: I've heard [*bystander effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect), which is mentioned in the *dissipation of responsibility* article.

Comment: The basic idea is often conveyed using the "wordplay" *If / When **everyone** is responsible **no-one** is responsible*.

Comment: I'd call it *Tweedledee and Tweedledum*.

Comment: [Mark Suster](https://bothsidesofthetable.com/never-ask-two-people-to-do-one-persons-job-6fc523dc55b3) includes the terms in his article subtitled 'Never ask two people to do one person's job'.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody’s business is nobody’s business
Here ‘business’ means ‘duty’ or ‘task’. When nobody is directly responsible for doing a thing, nobody does it, because everybody thinks somebody else is or will be doing it.  http://proverbhunter.com/everybodys-business-is-nobodys-business/

Answer (score 0):

"Fell through the cracks"

> to not be noticed or dealt with.
>
> - Little details often fall through the cracks.
> - Too many young people slip through the cracks in the health system.

[[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fall-through-the-cracks)

Answer (score 0):

The almost identical English phrase is [falling between two stools](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-between-two-stools) which, as the Cambrige dictionary entry under the link shows, is idiomatic and carries an almost identical meaning.

It is used, however, to describe many other situations as well: for example someone who tries to follow two different career paths and achieves success in neither; a business which tries to do two incompatible things and does neither of them well or a film which tries to be both comic and serious but fails to convince on either count.

Given the long history of common development of the French and English languages it is possible that the two idioms have the same origin.